# [int]::MaxValue inside powershell function

Tags: powershell

Somehow i got the issue that the function is assigning 0 to '$body."maxresults"'

```
function test {
    param(
        [Parameter()][string]$object_name,
        [Parameter()][int]$start_at,
        [Parameter()][int]$max_results
    )

    $dummy = [int]::MaxValue 

    $body = @{}
    $body."filters" = @()

    if ($start_at -ge 0)    {$body."start_at"=$start_at}        else{$body."start_at"="0"}
    if ($max_results -ge 0) {$body."max_results"=$max_results}  else{$body."max_results"=$dummy}
    if ($object_name)       {$body.filters += @{"filter_identifier"="object_name"; "object_name"=$object_name}}
}

$start_at = 30
$ant = test -object_name "test" -start_at $start_at
$ant
```

the result is this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           ----
start_at                       30
max_results                    0
filters                        {System.Collections.Hashtable}
```

But when I define '$dummy = [int]::MaxValue' outside the function and pass it to the function it works:

```
function test {
    param(
        [Parameter()][string]$object_name,
        [Parameter()][int]$start_at,
        [Parameter()][int]$max_results
    )

    $body = @{}
    $body."filters" = @()

    if ($start_at -ge 0)    {$body."start_at"=$start_at}        else{$body."start_at"="0"}
    if ($max_results -ge 0) {$body."max_results"=$max_results}  else{$body."max_results"=$dummy}
    if ($object_name)       {$body.filters += @{"filter_identifier"="object_name"; "object_name"=$object_name}}
}

$start_at = 30 
$max_results = [int]::MaxValue 
$ant = test -object_name "test" -start_at $start_at -max_results $max_results
```

The result is then:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
start_at                       30
max_results                    2147483647
filters                        {System.Collections.Hashtable}
```

Does any one have a clue how to make '$dummy = [int]::MaxValue' inside the function work?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `-gt` rather than `-ge`

Comment: Yep, you're never entering the `else` condition if you don't assign a value and you use `-ge`, nice catch @mklement0

Answer (score 0):

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) has already pointed out in his helpful comment why you're getting these results, mainly, your comparison will always evaluate to `$true` whenever you give an argument to the `-max_results` parameter. This would be fixed by changing `-ge` for `-gt`. This answer is meant to show you a different approach you could take by refining your *`param(..)` block*, by doing so, no comparisons would be needed.

```
function test {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] # Seems like this param should be Mandatory
    [string]$object_name,
    [Parameter()]
    [int]$start_at = 0,
    [ValidateRange(0, [int]::MaxValue)] # A positive number,
    [int]$max_results = [int]::MaxValue # if no argument, assign `MaxValue`
                                        
)

    [ordered]@{
        "max_results" = $max_results
        "start_at" = $start_at
        "filters" = [object[]]@{
            "filter_identifier" = "object_name"
            "object_name"       = $object_name
        }
    }
}

test -object_name "test"
```